# Why doesn't my code using jQuery hasClass() work?

Tags: jquery

I am using hasClass method in my script but it is not working the way I want . 
My HTML table looks like this

```
<table id="sort">
            <tr class="nodrag nodrop">
                <td colspan=3><strong><a style="cursor:pointer;" class="toggle">Group 1</a></strong></td>
                <td style="text-align: right;"><a class="button3" href="#" ><span> Edit </span></a> <a class="button3" href="#" ><span> Delete </span></a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="1" class="tr_group" style='display:none;'>
                <td style="width:10px;" class="dragHandle">&nbsp;</td>
                <td><a href=# style="margin-left: 20px;">Umair Iqbal</a></td>
                <td><span style="font-size: 12px; color: #999; line-height: 100%;">A Student at TUM</span></td>
                <td style="text-align: right;"><a class="button3" href="#" ><span> Edit </span></a> <a class="button3" href="#" ><span> Delete </span></a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="2" class="tr_group" style='display:none;'>
                <td style="width:10px;" class="dragHandle">&nbsp;</td>
                <td><a href=# style="margin-left: 20px;">Faryal Khan</a></td>
                <td><span style="font-size: 12px; color: #999; line-height: 100%;">A Doctor at KMC</span></td>
                <td style="text-align: right;"><a class="button3" href="#" ><span> Edit </span></a> <a class="button3" href="#" ><span> Delete </span></a></td>
            </tr> 
</table>
```

My Script is as follows

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // $('#sort tr:even').addClass('alt');
            $('#sort').tableDnD({
                onDrop: function(table, row) {
                  alert(row.id);
                },
                dragHandle: ".dragHandle"
            });
            $("#sort tr").hover(function() {
                if($('#tr').hasClass('tr_group')) 
                {
                    $(this.cells[0]).addClass('showDragHandle');
                    }, function() {
                    $(this.cells[0]).removeClass('showDragHandle');
                }
            });
        });
 </script>
```

It is not adding the class showDragHandle to the rows which has class "tr_group" on hover effect

What I am doing wrong any suggestions ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no #tr. it shoud be $("tr")

Answer (score 1):

Your selectors are incorrect, you're using the hash to indicate and **id**.
Also you're prefixing your classes with an element notation that is not correct.

This

```
if($('#tr').hasClass('tr_group'))
```

should be:

```
if($('tr').hasClass('group'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Within `.hover`, you should be asking:

```
if ( $(this).hasClass("tr_group") )
```

Or you could respond only to those `tr` elements that have the class:

```
$("#sort").on({
    mouseenter: function(){
        $("td:first", this).addClass("showDragHandle");
    },
    mouseleave: function(){
        $("td:first", this).removeClass("showDragHandle");
    }
}, "tr.tr_group");
```

No need to do an if-statement when you can respond to only the `tr` elements you're targeting.

Answer (score 0):

There is no element with an ID of `tr`

You probably want:

```
if ($(this).hasClass('group'))
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response :) Exactly

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
$(this.cells[0])
```

Use:

```
$('.dragHandle', $(this))
```

Also change:

```
$('#tr')
```

To:

```
$('tr')
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

`if($('#tr').hasClass('tr_group'))`

to

`if($(this).hasClass('tr_group'))`

since you are already iterating over a list of trs.